# Compare minutes in XSLT or replace character

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0

I have an XML file (1.0) with song durations in minutes format (x: xx) I wanted to know how to compare the duration(duracion) of the songs by one that I put for example those that last less than 3:40, and be able to show them next to the When they album, I can't find how to compare minutes, he tried to replace the: by '' so he could compare numbers, but neither could he.
Anyone who can help me? Thank you.

```
<disco>
    <titulo>Arriva</titulo>
    <fechaLanzamiento>2014</fechaLanzamiento>
    <productor>Tiempo Real</productor>
    <portada>arriva.jpg</portada>
    <tracklist>
        <track>
            <cancion>Oh, Oui Oui</cancion>
            <duracion>3:22</duracion>
        </track>
        <track>
            <cancion>Fan</cancion>
            <duracion>3:32</duracion>
        </track>
        <track>
            <cancion>Fantasmas</cancion>
            <duracion>4:02</duracion>
        </track>
        <track>
            <cancion>Salta</cancion>
            <duracion>3:20</duracion>
        </track>
        <track>
            <cancion>Fiesta</cancion>
            <duracion>3:42</duracion>
        </track>
        <track>
            <cancion>Subimos</cancion>
            <duracion>3:27</duracion>
        </track>
        <track>
            <cancion>Reina</cancion>
            <duracion>3:16</duracion>
        </track>
        <track>
            <cancion>Ilegal</cancion>
            <duracion>4:12</duracion>
        </track>
        <track>
            <cancion>Playa</cancion>
            <duracion>3:38</duracion>
        </track>
        <track>
            <cancion>Navidad</cancion>
            <duracion>4:03</duracion>
        </track>
    </tracklist>
</disco>
<disco>
    <titulo>Safari Emocional</titulo>
    <fechaLanzamiento>2016</fechaLanzamiento>
    <productor>Hooke Management</productor>
    <portada>safari.jpg</portada>
    <tracklist>
        <track>
            <cancion>NingunoDos</cancion>
            <duracion>4:05</duracion>
        </track>
        <track>
            <cancion>Entre el Cielo y el Mar</cancion>
            <duracion>3:57</duracion>
        </track>
        <track>
            <cancion>Sonia y Selena</cancion>
            <duracion>3:37</duracion>
        </track>
        <track>
            <cancion>Los Amantes</cancion>
            <duracion>4:42</duracion>
        </track>
        <track>
            <cancion>Flow</cancion>
            <duracion>4:05</duracion>
        </track>
        <track>
            <cancion>Americana</cancion>
            <duracion>5:02</duracion>
        </track>
        <track>
            <cancion>Chicas</cancion>
            <duracion>4:27</duracion>
        </track>
        <track>
            <cancion>Vietnam</cancion>
            <duracion>3:34</duracion>
        </track>
        <track>
            <cancion>Momentos</cancion>
            <duracion>3:30</duracion>
        </track>
        <track>
            <cancion>Club</cancion>
            <duracion>3:52</duracion>
        </track>
        <track>
            <cancion>Metales Nocturnos</cancion>
            <duracion>3:22</duracion>
        </track>
        <track>
            <cancion>Callada</cancion>
            <duracion>4:34</duracion>
        </track>
    </tracklist>
</disco>
<disco>
    <titulo>Furor</titulo>
    <fechaLanzamiento>2018</fechaLanzamiento>
    <productor>Hook Management</productor>
    <portada>furor.jpg</portada>
    <tracklist>
        <track>
            <cancion>Un Nuevo Giro</cancion>
            <duracion>3:40</duracion>
        </track>
        <track>
            <cancion>El Sitio Perfecto</cancion>
            <duracion>3:39</duracion>
        </track>
        <track>
            <cancion>La Ruta del Amor</cancion>
            <duracion>3:37</duracion>
        </track>
        <track>
            <cancion>Las Noches Fugaces</cancion>
            <duracion>4:09</duracion>
        </track>
        <track>
            <cancion>Nada Personal</cancion>
            <duracion>3:46</duracion>
        </track>
        <track>
            <cancion>400 Bailes</cancion>
            <duracion>3:33</duracion>
        </track>
        <track>
            <cancion>Satánica</cancion>
            <duracion>4:13</duracion>
        </track>
        <track>
            <cancion>12yMedio</cancion>
            <duracion>3:47</duracion>
        </track>
        <track>
            <cancion>Medalla</cancion>
            <duracion>2:54</duracion>
        </track>
        <track>
            <cancion>Adiós</cancion>
            <duracion>3:19</duracion>
        </track>
    </tracklist>
</disco>
```

Comment: What is the expected result?

Answer (score 1):

Convert the duration to seconds using

```
number(substring-before($x, ':'))*60 + number(substring-after($x, ':'))
```